# Two different API calls - calculate exchange rate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm making two separate requests to different APIs to receive the [Bitcoin/USD] and then [GBP/USD]. I'm using `axios` to setup a `promise`, and on both calls successfully resolving, I'm setting both values to state `set.State{}`.

I'm trying to calculate the exchange rate between GBP/Bitcoin, but for the life of me can't wrap my head around how best to do it. It's also been a little while since I've used `React`, so any advice on improving what I've got would be great.

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      conv: [],
      GBP: [],
      XBT: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.all([this.getXbt(), this.getGbp()])
      .then(axios.spread( (xbtValue, gbpValue) => {
        const XBT = xbtValue.data.bpi.USD.rate_float;
        const GBP = gbpValue.data.rates.GBP;
        const conv = this.calcConversion(GBP, XBT);
        this.setState({conv, GBP, XBT});
      }));
  }

  calcConversion(x, y) {
    // Calculate conversion value here
    return x / y; 
  }

  getXbt() {
    return axios.get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/XBT.json');
  }

  getGbp() {
    return axios.get('https://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=#API_KEY#');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <div id="crypto-conversion">
            <span className="left">{this.state.conv}</span>
          </div>
          <div id="crypto-container">
            <span className="left">{this.state.GBP}</span>
            <span className="right">{this.state.XBT}</span>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the APIs are returning the data as `GBP/1USD` and `USD/1XBT`, then the conversion rate is simply the product of the two values and will result in `GBP/1XBT`.

> It's also been a little while since I've used React, so any advice on improving what I've got would be great.

Your code looks fine so far. I like the way you handled the API calls, and the `setState()` call follows convention as far as only calling it once.

Edit:

Also, I've just realized if you're willing to shell out $95/mo, the Open Exchange Rates API provides a [/convert](https://docs.openexchangerates.org/docs/convert) endpoint that supports `BTC`.